# Grafana status indicator if a docker service is down

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am looking for a way to indicate if a certain Docker service is up and running. Currently i am trying to use singlestat but this gives issues when no metrics are available. Is there any prefefered solution to achieve a status indicator for a specific service?

Comment: Did you find any solution using prometheus and grafana for this?

Comment: I recently did, so if this helps you then it would be great. The following query determines if a container is gone..

count(time() - container_last_seen{job="prometheus",name=~".*dummyping.*"} < 30) OR vector(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Prometheus Query answered my problem..

```
count(time() - container_last_seen{job="prometheus",name=~".*dummyping.*"} < 30) OR vector(0)
```

Comment: Hi Marco,I tried this and then i stopped one of my services by running
docker service scale <my-Service>=0. it did not show up in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Registrator and Consul will help you https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator